# Semicolons in superglobal $_COOKIE

Tags: php, inject, superglobals

when writing a class to access superglobals i just recognized php is removing semicolons from superglobals probably for security reasons.

e.g. when setting a cookie value to something like `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
i can see a variable dump that looks like `Array ( [cookie] => <?php phpinfo() [?>] => )` seeing the string containing semicolons being split in two or triming values up to the first occurence of a semicolon.

now here is the question.
**How is it possible to get the full string passed?**

As I am already "controlling" the variables passed I want to log a e.g. hexadecimal dump of the arbitrary payload using `unpack("H*",$booboostr)`.

So here is question two.
**How is it possible to to create a hexedecimal representation for the input?**

thank you in advance for any hints.
regards

Comment: Cookies require URL encoding.

Comment: so using something like `urlencode($_COOKIE["cookie"])` when trying to read/pass it on would do the trick?

Comment: Semicolon has special meaning in cookies, it's used to separate the value from options like domain, path, etc.

Comment: @MarcBredt It's also used to separate cookies: `cookie1=value1; cookie2=value2`

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing here. Why are you putting literal `<?php` into the cookie in the first place?

Comment: i am just testing my logging for unattended input in superglobals. e.g. i check for a regex to validate input but i additionally want to log arbitrary data in a session id like `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` would probably be. regarding this i just noticed the malforming when passing semicolons and asked myself if it is possible to log the complete string passed. at least it could be any other data not matching my regex.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Barmar's comment any $_COOKIE value with semicolons will be split to additional $_COOKIE key,value pairs if a section contains a "=" otherwise the data will be ommitted.

In short for $_COOKIE values there will be a double explosion for ";" and "=" invoked.

When a client modifies a cookie value for cookie key `sg` before (re)sending in a way that it looks like `firstval; foo=bar; omit-me; §$&%/&(/)=}][{ ¬½` it will lead to a $_COOKIE array with the following data on the server side instead of being a "simple" string for the cookie key `cookie`:

```
$_COOKIE = Array (
  [cookie] = firstval,
  [foo] = bar,
  [§$&%/&(/)] = ][{ ¬½
);
```

As you can see `omit-me` will be ommitted then which leads to the point one is not able to get the full string at once considering the conditions mentioned above.

Regards.

Comment: I don't think that's what he said. He said it was special in a cookie. Have you tried this with other global variables than `$_COOKIES`? This works fine for me: `$_SESSION["sg"] = 'firstval; foo=bar; omit-me; Â§$&%/&(/)=}][{ Â¬Â½';`

Comment: As you can see by the upvotes for @Barmar comments "[it is used to seperate the value from options or the cookies]" . this lead me to **complete** his comment falsely considering any superglobal. in the first i pointed at superglobals possibly being directly modified from the outside like _GET,_POST,_COOKIE where the exploding mechanism is slightly different. anyways i corrected my answer/thread title and restricted it to the superglobal $_COOKIE.

Comment: @miken32 tested your correction but as i am not setting a cookie value from the in-/server-side in my scenario using `$_COOKIE["foo"] = "anything";` where it would just work as expected setting "foo" to "anything" your correction differs slightly from my test case scenario with different effects.

Comment: Ok feel free to roll back the edit then. Cookie is getting set elsewhere and read by PHP?

Comment: The cookie's value is set through the client in my testing scenario.